# list of dataframes in R: assignment problem

Tags: r, list

I have the following code:

```
child_tracks <- list()
   for(i in 1:106)
   {
     for(j in 1:5)
     {
     child_tracks[[i]][[j]] <- 
all_samples[[i]][sample(nrow(all_samples[[i]]),length_breakups[[i]][[j]]),]

     }
   }
```

As above, "all_samples" is a list of dataframes, while "length_breakups" is a list of lists.

When I assign the calculation to it, it throws an error 
: subscript out of bounds. Although a singular variable can hold, a list 
can't. For example:

```
temp <- 
all_samples[[i]][sample(nrow(all_samples[[i]]),length_breakups[[i]][[j]]),]

child_tracks[[i]][[j]] <- 
all_samples[[i]][sample(nrow(all_samples[[i]]),length_breakups[[i]][[j]]),]
```

The former works, the latter doesn't. I've seen that the class 
definitions are all okay and so are the ranges of the "for" loop.

Just not getting around it. Any comments?

Answer (score 0):

Initialise the size of the list:

```
child_tracks <- array(list(), c(106,5))
   for(i in 1:106)
   {
     for(j in 1:5)
     {
     child_tracks[[i]][[j]] <- 
all_samples[[i]][sample(nrow(all_samples[[i]]),length_breakups[[i]][[j]]),]

     }
   }
```